# pip как правильно экранировать символ # в пароле?

Tags: proxy, python-3.5, pip

Здравствуйте.

Возникла необходимость накатить пакеты для python(3.5)/ОС Windows на сервере, который имеет подключение к Internet полько через прокси.
Попытался воспользоваться таким вариантом, НО он не сработал, т.к. pip неверно распознает пароль, он с особенностью в нем есть символ #.

```
“C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe” –-proxy http://user_proxy:pwd#123@proxy.new.ru:1111 install requests
```

Каким образом правильно экранировать # в пароле?

p.s. пробовал также такие варианты

```
    “C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe” –-proxy "http://user_proxy:pwd#123@proxy.new.ru:1111" install requests
    “C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe” –-proxy http://"user_proxy:pwd#123"@proxy.new.ru:1111 install requests
    “C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe” –-proxy http://user_proxy:"pwd#123"@proxy.new.ru:1111 install requests
```

результаты отрицательные :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо # необходимо было написать %23

Comment: в общем случае, можно попробовать `urllib.parse.quote(password)`.